# C#: loop through appdomains in assembly

Tags: c#

how to loop through appdomains in assembly?

Comment: What is the question here?  Do you want find out how many app domains are running in a process? What is the requirement?

Comment: try this : http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.clr/msg/9df14bf0af393c28?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

Source: [Thomas Scheidegger](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.clr/msg/9df14bf0af393c28?pli=1)

You need to add the following as a COM reference - ~\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscor ee.tlb. This works with currnet executing assembly. If you want to loop though processes and then get appdomain, that may not be possbile.

```
 public void GetAllAppDomains()
             {

                 AppDomain one = AppDomain.CreateDomain("One");
                 AppDomain two = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Two"); 
                // Creates 2 app domains           

                 List<AppDomain> appDomains = new List<AppDomain>();

                 IntPtr enumHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                 CorRuntimeHostClass host = new CorRuntimeHostClass();          

                 try
                 {

                     host.EnumDomains(out enumHandle);

                     object domain = null;

                     AppDomain tempDomain;

                     while (true)
                     {

                         host.NextDomain(enumHandle, out domain);

                         if (domain == null)
                         {
                             break;
                         }

                         tempDomain = domain as AppDomain;

                         appDomains.Add(tempDomain);

                     }               

                 }

                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());          
                 }

                 finally
                 {
                     host.CloseEnum(enumHandle);
                     int rel= Marshal.ReleaseComObject(host);
                 }

                 Assembly[] assemblies;
                 foreach (AppDomain app in appDomains)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(app.FriendlyName);

                     assemblies = app.GetAssemblies();

                     Console.WriteLine("-----------------------Assemblies------------------");
                     foreach (Assembly assem in assemblies)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(assem.FullName);
                     }
                     Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
                 }

             }
```

Comment: +1 as I didn't even think this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "in the process"... an `AppDomain` is such a significant item that you should really *know* when you are creating one, and track/manage the lifetime. There isn't an *easy* way to find all the `AppDomain`s in the process, AFAIK.